# Imbedding in the quasi-group

Tags: quasigroups

**Theorem:** Every finite quasi-group $G$ can be imbedded in a quasi-group $H$ generated by a single element.

Let $\varphi$ is the imbedding. Let $\langle h \rangle.$ Let $g_1 \in G$ and $\varphi(g_1) = h^i$ and $g_2 \in G$ and $\varphi(g_2) = h^j$.

Is it true that $g_1g_2 = \varphi^{-1}(h^{i+1})$?

Second question I have in my mind is

What is the size of $H$?

Comment: By the way, a proof is given [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=MXTmCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=Every+finite+quasi-group+G+can+be+imbedded+in+a+quasi-group+H+generated+by+a+single+element.&source=bl&ots=UqlKn491Kc&sig=ACfU3U2LhyJJgL1uiQu9j0QW60f6-PeSzA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjPtKu8jq7nAhWKKVAKHRLMDzYQ6AEwAHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=Every%20finite%20quasi-group%20G%20can%20be%20imbedded%20in%20a%20quasi-group%20H%20generated%20by%20a%20single%20element.&f=false).

Comment: You have to remember that in a quasigroup, powers are not necessarily well defined. $(h \cdot h)  \cdot h$ is not always the same as $h \cdot (h \cdot h)$ and so forth...